# dgruyter.sty with customized bibliographystyle

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I need to work with [`dgruyter.sty`](https://github.com/blockchain-lab/shared_vision_towards_programmable_economy/blob/master/tex/dgruyter.sty) to publish my book. They usually seem to work with `\bibliographystyle{plain}`, which works well with this `.sty` file, but since I'm publishing in a specific series, I need a different bibliography style. The one I would like to use is the following: [`bzrp.bst`](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10W586B_AKrzYpBi4XsC-V1e3xaQrBI9o)

My colleague who created this bibliography style indicated to use the following command with it :

```
  \usepackage[bibstyle=bzrp,natbib=true,citestyle=authoryear,maxitems=2,minitems=1,maxnames=2,minnames=1,urldate=long]{biblatex}
  \def\bibfont{\small }
```

My code is the following:

```
\documentclass[openany,ngerman]{book}
  \usepackage[small]{dgruyter}
  \usepackage{microtype}
  \baretabulars
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage[main=french,italian, spanish, portuguese, latin, greek]{babel}
  \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
  \usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
  \usepackage{slantsc}
  \usepackage[T1]{tipa}
  \newcommand\ie[1]{\textipa{\itshape{#1}}}
  \usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
  \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
  \usepackage[nottoc, notlof, notlot]{tocbibind}

   \begin{document}
  \frontmatter
  \maketitle
  \dedication{...\\ ...}

   \subsection{Focus sur la reconstruction en domaine roman}    
    Or, déjà au 18\textsuperscript{e} siècle, Pierre Bonamy a affirmé que l'origine des parlers romans \blockquote{n'est autre chose que la langue [latine] parlée et employée dans les discours familiers} (\sqcitet{Bonamy}, 586, cité par \sqcitet{VanAckerReflexions}, 596). Cette approche représentait un grand pas en avant pour la romanistique, mais ella a dû attendre le 19\textsuperscript{e} siècle, avec \citet{MeyerLubke1901}, 82 comme précurseur, pour accepter, en théorie, que les langues romanes remontent au latin parlé. Peu à peu, les romanistes en sont arrivés à convenir qu'en raison de la différence notable entre le latin écrit et le latin parlé dans l'Empire romain, due à l'évolution plus rapide de ce dernier, les langues romanes sont la source principale d'accès à ce qu'on est convenu d'appeler le \textit{latin vulgaire} (cf. \sqcitet{Benarroch2013}, 4). Cependant, la pratique lexicographique a dû attendre l'année 2008 (*/\textquotesingle{}kad-e-/: 08/08/2008) pour voir apparaître autre chose que des lexèmes en graphie du latin écrit de l'Antiquité comme étymons des lexèmes héréditaires romans (cf. ci-dessous et cf. \sqcitet{Chambon2014}, 145, 153).\\

  \backmatter
  \bibliographystyle{bzrp}
  \bibliography{bibliographie}
  \end{document}
```

I really would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dgruyter.pdf` companion to the `dgruyter.sty` available from https://www.degruyter.com/page/production-for-authors (specifically [this `.zip` archive](https://www.degruyter.com/staticfiles/pdfs/AUTH_DG_LaTeX-Template.zip), if you want to obtain the `.sty` file from the files in the archive, run `pdflatex dgruyter.ins`) has the following to say about bibliographies

> It is recommended to use the standard bibliography mechanism. You might copy
>   and paste your bibliography entries from elsewhere into the `thebibliography` environment or, more elegantly, use BibTeX. The `dgruyter` package does not prescribe
>   any particular bibliography style.
>
> The `natbib` package can be loaded additionally, so an author-year-style bibliography layout is possible. The special citing commands `\citet`, `\citep` and so on can
>   be used. Feel free to configure `natbib`, e.g. with `\setcitestyle{numbers}` in your
>   document preamble to force the numerical mode.
>
> Alternatively, the `biblatex` package can be used. Be aware, however, that there is
>   an abundance of options which have not all been tested for compatibility with the
>   `dgruyter` package. The following seem to work fine for the numeric style:
>
> - `\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}` to load the package,
> - `\addbibresource{BIBFILE}` to load the .bib-file,
> - `\printbibliography[env=bibnumeric]` to output the bibliography.
>     With author-year citation you have to skip the optional argument of
>     `\printbibliography`.

So I would try to avoid `biblatex` if possible or at least try to clear the usage of `biblatex` with the responsible editor (or another contact at de Gruyter).

---

There is a confusion about BibTeX styles and `biblatex` styles here, so we must shortly address some terminology.

The big two ways to produce bibliographies semi-automatically in LaTeX are with BibTeX and `biblatex`. You can read much more about their pros and cons at [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864) and a bit about the history (as I understand it) at [A design question: citation commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/473471/35864).

The important bit for us is that bibliography styles for BibTeX-based solutions are given in a `.bst` file and loaded with `\bibliographystyle` (the citation style is controlled by `\usepackage`s like `cite`, `natbib` etc. in combination with a compatible `.bst` file). Such that a document using the BibTeX style `plainnat` with `natbib` looks roughly like this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
A bare citation command: \citep{sigfridsson}.

A citation command for use in the flow of text: As \citet{sigfridsson} said \dots

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\end{document}
```

For `biblatex` the bibliography style is implemented in a `.bbx` file and the citation style in a `.cbx` file. These files are loaded with the `style` option (or separately with `bibstyle` and `citestyle`) when you load `biblatex`. An example using `biblatex`'s `numeric` style would look like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
A bare citation command: \citep{sigfridsson}.

A citation command for use in the flow of text: As \citet{sigfridsson} said \dots

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

You can read more about the transition from BibTeX to `biblatex` at [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864).

---

The file `bzrp.bst` you link has the file ending `.bst` and one would therefore be inclined to think it is a BibTeX style that is used like `plainnat` in the example above. But if one opens the file and examines it, the first line one finds is

```
\ProvidesFile{bzrp.bbx}[2008/01/04 bzrp biblatex bibliography style]
```

and indeed, the remaining contents of the file make it clear that this is actually a `biblatex` style. So the file must be renamed to `bzrp.bbx` and then used like `numeric` in the `biblatex` example above. Since the style is lacking a companion `.cbx` citation style it probable needs to be used at least like

```
\usepackage[bibstyle=bzrp,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
```

this comes close to what your colleague suggested (minus some other settings).

A first attempt from your code above (I removed packages that were not relevant for the example, moved `babel` to before `dgruyter` to avoid an option clash error and remove the global `ngerman` option and replaced the [non-standard `\sqcitet`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/385540/35864) by `\textcite`) could thus be

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage[main=french,italian, spanish, portuguese, latin, greek]{babel}
\usepackage[small]{dgruyter}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[bibstyle=bzrp,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Or, déjà au 18\textsuperscript{e} siècle, Pierre Bonamy a affirmé
que l'origine des parlers romans
\blockquote{n'est autre chose que la langue [latine]
parlée et employée dans les discours familiers}
(\textcite{cicero}, 586, cité par \textcite{sigfridsson}, 596).
Cette approche représentait un grand pas en avant pour la romanistique,
mais ella a dû attendre le 19\textsuperscript{e} siècle, avec \textcite{worman},
82 comme précurseur, pour accepter, en théorie,
que les langues romanes remontent au latin parlé.
Peu à peu, les romanistes en sont arrivés à convenir qu'en
raison de la différence notable entre le latin écrit et le latin
parlé dans l'Empire romain, due à l'évolution plus rapide de ce dernier,
les langues romanes sont la source principale d'accès à ce qu'on est
convenu d'appeler le \textit{latin vulgaire} (cf. \textcite{geer}, 4).
Cependant, la pratique lexicographique a dû attendre l'année 2008
(*/\textquotesingle{}kad-e-/: 08/08/2008) pour voir apparaître
autre chose que des lexèmes en graphie du latin écrit de l'Antiquité
comme étymons des lexèmes héréditaires romans 
(cf. ci-dessous et cf. \textcite{nussbaum}, 145, 153).

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, if you try to run this code on a relatively recent LaTeX system, you will get errors like

> ```
> ! Illegal parameter number in definition of \blx@defformat@d.
> <to be read again> 
>                    3
> l.15  #1\ifblank{#3
>                    }{}{\addcomma\space #3}
> ```

That is because the file predates the changes in `biblatex` 3.3 that are discussed in [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864). (Indeed, the file header suggests the file was last changed in 2008, more than twelve years ago and even well before the first stable release of `biblatex` 1.0 in November 2010.)

`bzrp.bbx` is completely outdated and not compatible with a current version of `biblatex`. It might be possible to change it as explained in [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864) so that it compiles again with current `biblatex` versions, but `biblatex` has progressed a lot since the style was written, so that might not be enough. It may be easier to just start anew. I could not find any mentions of this style online, so I can't help you with contacting the author for support, I'm afraid.

The following compiles without any issues

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage[main=french,italian, spanish, portuguese, latin, greek]{babel}
\usepackage[small]{dgruyter}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Or, déjà au 18\textsuperscript{e} siècle, Pierre Bonamy a affirmé
que l'origine des parlers romans
\blockquote{n'est autre chose que la langue [latine]
parlée et employée dans les discours familiers}
\mkbibparens{\textcite[586]{cicero}, cité par \textcite[596]{sigfridsson}}.
Cette approche représentait un grand pas en avant pour la romanistique,
mais ella a dû attendre le 19\textsuperscript{e} siècle, avec \textcite[82]{worman}
comme précurseur, pour accepter, en théorie,
que les langues romanes remontent au latin parlé.
Peu à peu, les romanistes en sont arrivés à convenir qu'en
raison de la différence notable entre le latin écrit et le latin
parlé dans l'Empire romain, due à l'évolution plus rapide de ce dernier,
les langues romanes sont la source principale d'accès à ce qu'on est
convenu d'appeler le \textit{latin vulgaire} \parencite[cf.][4]{geer}.
Cependant, la pratique lexicographique a dû attendre l'année 2008
(*/\textquotesingle{}kad-e-/: 08/08/2008) pour voir apparaître
autre chose que des lexèmes en graphie du latin écrit de l'Antiquité
comme étymons des lexèmes héréditaires romans 
\mkbibparens{cf. ci-dessous et \textcite[cf.][145, 153]{nussbaum}}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

but of course it doesn't look quite like what `bzrp.bbx` would give you.